# Register AVPlayer for events - how to know AVPlayer is done playing movie

Tags: ios, avplayer

I know that AVPlayerItem (a subclass of AVPlayer) is able to subscribe to the `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification`

AVPlayer does not have such capability, and I need to use AVPlayer unless there is no way around this and know when the playing of the (video in my case) is complete.

How do I do this in an AVPlayer? I read some of the documentation for these classes and I do not see an immediate answer.

```
-(void)setupVideoView{


    _videoPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:urlObjectHere];

    AVPlayerLayer *layer = [AVPlayerLayer layer];

    [layer setPlayer:_videoPlayer];
    [layer setFrame:_videoView.bounds];

    [_videoView.layer addSublayer:layer];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(itemDidFinishPlaying:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:_videoPlayer];




}

-(void)itemDidFinishPlaying:(NSNotification *) notification {
    // does not get called

    DLog(@"");



}
```

Comment: Should I scrap it and go with MPMoviePlayer instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem in the following way: I used an AVPlayerItem and created my AVPlayer from that item, subscribing the notifications to the player item.

```
-(void)setupVideoView{


     AVPlayerItem* playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:urlObjectHere];//edited

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(itemDidFinishPlaying:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:playerItem];//edited

    _videoPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];//edited

    AVPlayerLayer *layer = [AVPlayerLayer layer];

    [layer setPlayer:_videoPlayer];
    [layer setFrame:_videoView.bounds];

    [_videoView.layer addSublayer:layer];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(itemDidFinishPlaying:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:_videoPlayer];




}

-(void)itemDidFinishPlaying:(NSNotification *) notification {
    // gets called finally


    AVPlayerItem *p = [notification object]; //bring video back to zero
    [p seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];

    DLog(@"");



}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I know, there's no way to know the complete time by AVPlayer layer.

AVAsset - AVPlayerItem - AVPlayer are three components combined AVPlayer in AVFoundation. If you want DIY more functions of AVPlayer, you need to use lower level of AVPlayer, they are AVAsset and AVPlayerItem.

If you just need normal utilities of AVPlayer, just use AVPlayerViewController in AVKit I think.

It's not suggested to use MPMoviePlayer, most part of it has deprecated. Get used to AVPlayer...

Comment: I see, thank you for this. Had no idea MPMoviePlayer was deprecated. I want to use AVPlayerItem. How do I make it play inside of a UIView and call play/pause on it?

Comment: thanks again, I was able to solve my problem by using AVPlayerItem.

Comment: No problem, only way I know about complete time in AVPlayer is that you know, by NSNotificationCenter, that's correct

About play and pause, there are two instance method [yourplayer play]; and [yourplayer pause]; and you can judge if yourplayer.rate > 0 to know if it's playing or not, rate is the playing speed of your player